# Apex Web Service Authentication for .Net CF client

Tags: web-services, compact-framework, oracle-apex

We are developing a barcode application to run on our mobile computers running Windows Mobile 5.0 Pocket PC and it needs to get it's data from our Oracle database.

Apex is already set up but how can I create a secure Web Service using Apex's native Authentication? How to set "HTTPS only"?

Update

I can call the ...?wsdl link in the browser now, looks fine. It's also registered in the project as a WebReferance.

But when I run the following code:

```
CONTAR_USUARIOSService service = new CONTAR_USUARIOSService();
System.Net.NetworkCredential pocket = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("pocket", "000");
service.Credentials = pocket;
double resultado = service.CONTAR_USUARIOS();
```

I get this error:

```
System.Net.WebException was unhandled
  Message="WebException"
  StackTrace:
       at System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol.doInvoke(String     methodName, Object[] parameters, WebClientAsyncResult asyncResult)
       at System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol.Invoke(String methodName, Object[] parameters)
       at Supernorte.Recebimento.ContarUsuariosWebReference.CONTAR_USUARIOSService.CONTAR_USUARIOS()
       at Supernorte.Recebimento.Login..ctor()
       at Supernorte.Recebimento.MainForm.mostrarLogin()
       at Supernorte.Recebimento.MainForm..ctor()
       at Supernorte.Recebimento.Program.Main()
```

I get an "Unauthorized" error.

Comment: I don't think Windows Mobile 5 supports "HTTPS". I did this on our WM5 apps by created db connections directly to our SQL Server.

Comment: I can only use Oracle. But I found out about Oracle XML DB, it can expose database objects through web services. Having some hard times with it too... I'll post some updates.

Comment: I'm still struggling with web services, too, so I'm not the best resource. I'll see if I can find something on what I did...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I didn't use Apex as I intended. Instead I enabled [Oracle XML DB Native Web Services](http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/11g/native-oracle-xml-db-web-services-11gr1.php).

After some hard times with authentication [mostly caused by typing the wrong password ): ] I got this code working:

```
MyWebService service = new MyWebService();
service.Credentials = new MyWebService("MY_ORACLE_USER", "*******");

double result = service.MY_LOGIN_FUNCTION(this.userName);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you get your Oracle inputs and outputs routed through your web service (which I am still personally struggling with), you might be able to access your information that way.

Add the web reference.

[image: Add Web Reference]

It will ask for the URL where your Web Service has been uploaded. I'm guessing this can be a website you own off site, but I use our internal server.

[image: cpweb2 mainframe]

You can see I have a default web page where I load up the available services that I've stuck out there. 1Mainframe.svc` was going to be my "Big Service", but then I realized that I needed to do a lot more than make that once call, so I created the next one, "Erp Service".

Anyway, after I select the `ErpService.svc`, I'm given this, where I changed the default Web Reference Name to **ErpService1**. I've personally found that if I need to edit or modify the service, the XML config files get all messed up, so I just delete Service1 and add Service2.

I add a new class called **ErpClass1.cs**

[image: Erp Class 1]

Add a reference to my Web Service using the namespace for my project, and start coding!

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using AcpMobile5.ErpService1;

namespace AcpMobile5 {

  class ErpClass1 {

    private ErpService m_erpService;

    public ErpClass1() {
      m_erpService = new ErpService();
    }

    public void Query(string woNumber) {
      m_erpService.Query(woNumber);
    }

    public string PartNumber() {
      return m_erpService.CoilPartNo();
    }

  }

}
```

Obviously, this does not solve everything for you. The Web Service that you use to access your Oracle database still needs to be written, and that's no simple task.

However, I hope it helps point you along the right direction.

This is all done using Visual Studio 2008 for Mobile 5.0.

[image: GUI Screenshot]